Gradle Kotlin DSL: Import dependency into cache from libs folder before build
Question
How do I force Gradle to download a missing dependency when it keeps looking in a cache directory?
I have cleaned up my Gradle file so you can see what the baseline looks like:
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.Detekt
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.DetektCreateBaselineTask
import org.jetbrains.intellij.platform.gradle.TestFrameworkType
import org.jetbrains.intellij.platform.gradle.extensions.intellijPlatform

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.24"
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij.platform") version "2.1.0"
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.23.5"
}

group = "com.balsdon"
version = System.getenv("VERSION_NUMBER")

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    intellijPlatform {
        defaultRepositories()
    }
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

intellijPlatform {
    pluginConfiguration {
        name = "android_ally"
        group = "com.balsdon.android-ally-plugin"
        ideaVersion.sinceBuild.set(project.property("sinceBuild").toString())
        ideaVersion.untilBuild.set(provider { null })
    }
    buildSearchableOptions.set(false)
    instrumentCode = true

    signing {
        privateKey = System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")
        password = System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD")
        certificateChain = System.getenv("CERTIFICATE_CHAIN")
    }

    publishing {
        token = System.getenv("PUBLISH_TOKEN")
    }
}

dependencies {
    intellijPlatform {
        bundledPlugin("org.jetbrains.android")
        instrumentationTools()
        testFramework(TestFrameworkType.Platform)
        zipSigner()
        if (project.hasProperty("localIdeOverride")) {
            local(property("localIdeOverride").toString())
        } else {
            androidStudio(property("ideVersion").toString())
        }
    }

    // ----- Production dependencies -----
    val rxJava = "3.1.8"
    // RxJava
    implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:$rxJava")

    // ----- Signing -----
    // @see https://github.com/JetBrains/marketplace-zip-signer
    val zipSigner = "0.1.8"
    implementation(dependencyNotation = "org.jetbrains:marketplace-zip-signer:$zipSigner")
    // ----- Testing -----
    val googleTruth = "1.1.4"
    // Google truth
    testImplementation("com.google.truth:truth:$googleTruth")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
}

detekt {
    buildUponDefaultConfig = true // preconfigure defaults
    allRules = false // activate all available (even unstable) rules.
    config.setFrom("$projectDir/config/detekt.yaml") // point to your custom config defining rules to run, overwriting default behavior
    baseline = file("$projectDir/config/baseline.xml") // a way of suppressing issues before introducing detekt
}

tasks {
    // Set the JVM compatibility versions
    val projectJvmTarget = "17"
    val projectApiVersion = "1.8"

    withType<Detekt>().configureEach {
        reports {
            html.required.set(true) // observe findings in your browser with structure and code snippets
            xml.required.set(true) // checkstyle like format mainly for integrations like Jenkins
            txt.required.set(true) // similar to the console output, contains issue signature to manually edit baseline files
            sarif.required.set(true) // standardized SARIF format (https://sarifweb.azurewebsites.net/) to support integrations with GitHub Code Scanning
            md.required.set(true) // simple Markdown format
        }
    }

    withType<Detekt>().configureEach {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    withType<DetektCreateBaselineTask>().configureEach {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildSearchableOptions {
        enabled = false
    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = projectJvmTarget
    }

    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = projectJvmTarget
    }

    withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = projectJvmTarget
        targetCompatibility = projectJvmTarget
    }

    withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = projectJvmTarget
        all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = jvmTarget
                apiVersion = projectApiVersion
            }
        }
    }

    runIde {
        jvmArgs = listOf("-Xmx4096m", "-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions")
    }
}

Output:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find /Users/USER/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4297f39e97ad9447a15d9076b40348cc/transformed/android-studio-2024.2.1.9-mac_arm/plugins/performanceTesting/lib/performanceTesting.jar-242.21829.142.2421.12409432+517.jar (bundledModule:com.jetbrains.performancePlugin:242.21829.142.2421.12409432+517).
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4297f39e97ad9447a15d9076b40348cc/transformed/android-studio-2024.2.1.9-mac_arm/plugins/performanceTesting/lib/performanceTesting.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Discussion
There is a known issue when building Android Studio plugins. The missing dependecy is performanceTesting.jar there is a downloadable jar file, that when put into the appropriate cache, will fix the build.
The problem I am having is that I build on a remote (Github Actions) pipeline. I can't just guess which cache folder to put it in because the UUID might be different. Also, I can't just copy the dependency into the appropriate cache folder because every time my build runs it's running from an inflated instance, meaning that the cache folder doesn't exist each time (as opposed to fixing it locally after a failure, because the cache directory will persist)
What I have tried
Many of my original attempts can just be seen in commits, but I'll add some others afterwards.

Branch 1
Branch 2

Trying to follow "Put jar file to cache manually" and "Include local javadoc with gradle"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        url = uri(file("libs/performance-testing-242.23339.19.jar"))
    }
    ...
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        url = uri(file("libs/performance-testing-242.23339.19.jar"))
        metadataSources {
            artifact()
        }
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("performance-testing-242.23339.19.jar"))))    
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(files("libs/performance-testing-242.23339.19.jar"))
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation(files("libs/performance-testing-242.23339.19.jar"))    
    ...
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jetbrains.intellij.performanceTesting/performance-testing
    runtimeOnly("com.jetbrains.intellij.performanceTesting:performance-testing:242.21829.142")
    ...
}

Bad solutions
I've also tried writing a custom function to download the artefact, but the problem is the cache needs to exist! If I run this after the build fails, then I would need a second task that not only re-tries the build, but overrides the fact that the first attempt failed, which seems like a process rabbit hole.
fun performanceTestCheck() {
    if (extra["ideVersion"] != "2024.2.1.9") {
        println("performanceTestCheck Fix not applied outside of LadyBug")
        return
    }
    val homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home")
    println("performanceTestCheck running in [${homeDir}]")
    // get the cache lib dir
    val filteredDirs = fileTree("$homeDir/.gradle/caches/transforms-3").filter {
        it.path.contains("/transformed/") && it.path.contains("android-studio-2024.2.1.9")
    }
    println("        ------------------------------------------------------------")
    fileTree("$homeDir/.gradle/caches/transforms-3").forEach { println("        [${it.path}]") }
    println("        ------------------------------------------------------------")
    filteredDirs.forEach {
        println("        [${it.path}]")
    }
    println("        ------------------------------------------------------------")

    val targetCacheDir = filteredDirs.map {
        it.path
            .replace("$homeDir/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/", "")
            .substringBefore("/")
    }.toSet()

    if (targetCacheDir.isEmpty() || targetCacheDir.size > 1) {
        println("performanceTestCheck: Not sure what to do in this situation [targetCacheDir.size=${targetCacheDir.size}]")
        return
    }

    val androidStudio = fileTree("$homeDir/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/${targetCacheDir.first()}/transformed")
        .first()
        .path
        .replace("$homeDir/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/${targetCacheDir.first()}/transformed/", "")
        .substringBefore("/")

    val destinationRoot =
        "$homeDir/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/${targetCacheDir.first()}/transformed/${androidStudio}/plugins/"

    File("${destinationRoot}/performanceTesting").apply {
        if (!exists()) {
            println("performanceTestCheck(): creating directory performanceTesting")
            createDirectory()
        }
    }
    File("${destinationRoot}/performanceTesting/lib").apply {
        if (!exists()) {
            println("performanceTestCheck(): creating directory performanceTesting/lib")
            createDirectory()
        }
    }
    val destinationPath = "${destinationRoot}/performanceTesting/lib/"
    val performanceTestingFile = File("${destinationRoot}/performanceTesting/lib/performance-testing-242.23339.19.jar")
    if (performanceTestingFile.exists()) {
        println("performanceTestCheck(): performanceTesting.jar dependency exists")
    } else {
        println("performanceTestCheck(): performanceTesting.jar not dependency found")
        val webURL =
            "https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/performanceTesting/performance-testing/242.23339.19/performance-testing-242.23339.19.jar"
        download(webURL, destinationPath)
        println("performanceTestCheck(): performanceTesting.jar downloaded")
    }
}

